# Mocking a REST call with MockRestServiceServer

Tags: java, spring, rest, junit

I'm trying to write a JUnit test case which tests a method in a helper class. The method calls an external application using REST and it's this call that I am trying to mock in the JUnit test.

The helper method makes the REST call using Spring's RestTemplate.

In my test, I create a mock REST server and mock REST template and instanitiate them like this:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(helperClass.getRestTemplate());
}
```

I then seed the mock server so that it should return an appropriate response when the helper method makes the REST call:

```
// response is some XML in a String
mockServer
    .expect(MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo(new URI(myURL)))
    .andExpect(MockRestRequestMatchers.method(HttpMethod.GET))
    .andRespond(MockRestResponseCreators.withStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        .body(response));
```

When I run my test, the helper method receives a null response from the REST call it makes and the test fails.

The REST URL that the helper makes has query params and looks like this: "http://server:port/application/resource?queryparam1=value1&queryparam2=value2".

I've tried putting the URL ("http://server:port/application/resource") both with *and* without the query parameters in the "myURL" variable (to elicit a match so that it returns a response), but can not get the mock server to return anything.

I've tried searching for examples of this kind of code but have yet to find anything which seems to resemble my scenario.

Spring version 4.1.7.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Thanks for writing the class to the static methods unlike many other sources where it's just, e.g. `requestTo`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you create an instance of `MockRestServiceServer` you should use existing instance of `RestTemplate` that is being used by your production code. So try to inject `RestTemplate` into your test and use it when invoking `MockRestServiceServer.createServer` - don't create new `RestTemplate` in your tests.

Comment: The issue was my mistake. I was using a mocked RestTemplate object for the tests, rather than a properly-instantiated one as per your suggestion. Once this was replaced, the tests ran successfully.

Comment: I am facing problems with testing RestTemplate as well. However, in my case, I don't have access to the RestTemplate instance. The code in my helper class is like `new RestTemplate().exchange(uri,HttpMethod.GET,...)`. How can I test this.

Comment: Thank you so much for such an important point, I been struggling with this from 1 month. and this was the tricky part (So obvious) and not able to see. Thanks
Can we mock the feign clients as well?

Answer (score 4):

Seems that you are trying to test the rest-client, the rest-server should be tested in other place.
You are using RestTemplate -> To call the service. Then, tried to mock RestTemplate and its call's results.

```
@Mock
RestTemplate restTemplateMock;
```

and Service Under Test Class

```
@InjectMocks
Service service;
```

Let say, Service has a method to be test as

```
public void filterData() {
   MyResponseModel response = restTemplate.getForObject(serviceURL, MyResponseModel.class);
   // further processing with response
}
```

Then, to test filterData method, you need to mock the response from restTemplate call such as

```
mockResponseModel = createMockResponse();
Mockito.when(restTemplateMock.getForObject(serviceURL, MyResponseModel.class)).thenReturn(mockResponseModel);

service.filterData();
//Other assert/verify,... go here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new instance of RestTemplate however you have to pass it in your createServer method like this:

```
private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
client.setRestTemplate(restTemplate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

these are the two ways i understand are possible, maybe there are better ways -

#### Solution 1

use `@RestClientTest`.
we would not have to instantiate `MockRestServiceServer`

```java
@Service
public class RemoteVehicleDetailsService {

  private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

  public RemoteVehicleDetailsService(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.build();
  }
```

```java
@RestClientTest({ RemoteVehicleDetailsService.class })
class MyRestClientTests {

  @Autowired
  RemoteVehicleDetailsService service;

  @Autowired
  MockRestServiceServer server;
```

[github](https://github.com/philwebb/testing-spring-boot-applications/blob/master/src/test/java/sample/service/RemoteVehicleDetailsServiceTest.java), [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.autoconfigured-rest-client)

---

#### Solution 2

what [@Rafal G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743716/rafal-g) said
create `RestTemplate` outside the `RemoteVehicleDetailsService` (note how in solution 1 it was being created inside the constructor of the service)
the same `RestTemplate` has to be used in both places - to create `MockRestServiceServer` and inside the actual service implementation

```java
@Service
public class RemoteVehicleDetailsService {

  private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

  public RemoteVehicleDetailsService(RestTemplate vehicleDetailsRt) {
    this.restTemplate = vehicleDetailsRt;
  }
```

```java
@SpringBootTest
class MyRestClientTests {

  @Autowired
  RestTemplate vehicleDetailsRt;

  MockRestServiceServer server;

  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {
    mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(vehicleDetailsRt);
  }
```