# How to mock local RestTemplate in Java Spring?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mockito

```
public class ServiceTest {
    @Mock
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    @InjectMocks
    Service service = new Service();
    ResponseEntity responseEntity = mock(ResponseEntity.class);

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(restTemplate.getForEntity(
                Mockito.anyString(),
                Matchers.any(Class.class)
                ))
                .thenReturn(responseEntity);
        boolean res = service.isEnabled("something");
        Assert.assertEquals(res, false);
    }
```

I tried to test a simple test for a service including a restclient. It looks I have not Mock the `RestTemplate` successfully. It looks like the code get the real data not the mock one. Anyone can help me with this.

The service itself will looks as this:

```
public class Service{
    public boolean isEnabled(String xxx) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity("someurl",String.class);
        if(...)return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is that in your `isEnabled` you are creating a new RestTemplate.  This is wrong for two reasons, one is that you cannot mock it since you are creating a new one, and second it is good to avoid creating new objects per request.  RestTemplate is thread safe and hence can be a service class member, being used across many threads.

Change your service class to something like this:

```
public class Service{

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    public boolean isEnabled(String xxx) {
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity("someurl",String.class);
        if(...)return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now that your RestTemplate has become a class member you can now properly mock through one of two ways.  One, inject it using the `@InjectMock`, or use a setter method that you call from your test.

Since you are using InjectMock in your code we can go with that.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) 
public class ServiceTest {
    @Mock
    RestTemplate restTemplate;
    @InjectMocks
    @Spy
    Service service;
    ResponseEntity responseEntity = mock(ResponseEntity.class);

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(restTemplate.getForEntity(
                Mockito.anyString(),
                ArgumentMatchers.any(Class.class)
                ))
                .thenReturn(responseEntity);
        boolean res = service.isEnabled("something");
        Assert.assertEquals(res, false);
    }
```

Notice that I made a few changes.  First, I removed the `new RestTemplate()` and `new Service()`.  You should let mockito create those for you.  By annotating them with `@Mock` and `@Spy` you will ensure that Mockito will create them for you, and more importantly, will inject the mocks into your `service` object.

Answer (score 12):

Spring MVC's test framework has offered the class [`MockRestServiceServer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/MockRestServiceServer.html) for unit testing RESTful service code.

Here is a [tutorial](https://objectpartners.com/2013/01/09/rest-client-testing-with-mockrestserviceserver/) on its use.

Comment: I tried the tutorial but it does not work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37781982/mocking-a-rest-call-with-mockrestserviceserver

Answer (score 3):

If you use @Autowired, you could use MockRestServiceServer.
The below is the sample.

```
@Service
public class Service{
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public boolean isEnabled(String xxx) {
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity("someurl",String.class);
        if(...)return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

@Service needs to use @Autowired for creating object automatically.

Comment: I tried but it will return the error that restTemplate is null. And it looks I can not inject restTemplate bean. Is there anything else I can do to test it? I just need to mock the response of RestTemplete.

Comment: Sorry, I missed putting the importance annotation on the class. Please see my answer again.