# How mock REST Request

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I am using Mockito in JUnit and I have a method making a request to a microservice using *RestTemplate*.

```
private static final String REQUESTOR_API_HOST = "http://localhost:8090/requestor/v1/requestors/";

public TokenRequestorPayload getTokenRequestor(Long id) {
    restClient = new RestTemplate();
    return restClient.getForObject(REQUESTOR_API_HOST + id, TokenRequestorPayload.class);
}
```

This method returns a JSON object which will be deserialize in TokenRequestorPayload class.

When I execute unit tests they fail because mock didn't work and I got a *org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException*. How can I mock my RestTemplate?

Test

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = Mockito.spy(RestTemplate.class);
Mockito.doReturn(this.tokenRequestorMockJson()).when(restTemplate).getForObject(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.eq(TokenRequestorPayload.class));
```

Error

> org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on
>   GET request for "http://localhost:8090/requestor/v1/requestors/1":
>   Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Comment: Helps?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42406625/how-to-mock-resttemplate-in-java-spring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your test you are defining behavior for a mock instance of RestTemplate, which is good.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = Mockito.spy(RestTemplate.class);
```

However, the same instance is not used by the Class Under Test which creates a new RestTemplate instance each time and uses that one.

```
public TokenRequestorPayload getTokenRequestor(Long id, RestTemplate restClient) {
    restClient = new RestTemplate(); // it uses this instance, not the mock
    return restClient.getForObject(REQUESTOR_API_HOST + id, TokenRequestorPayload.class);
}
```

So you need to find a way to bring the mock instance to the getTokenRequestor() method.

**E.g.** this can be accomplished by turning `restClient` into a method parameter:

```
public TokenRequestorPayload getTokenRequestor(Long id, RestTemplate restClient) {
    return restClient.getForObject(REQUESTOR_API_HOST + id, TokenRequestorPayload.class);
}
```

and the test might look something like like:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    RestTemplate restTemplateMock = Mockito.spy(RestTemplate.class);
    Mockito.doReturn(null).when(restTemplateMock).getForObject(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.eq(TokenRequestorPayload.class));

    // more code

    instance.getTokenRequestor(id, restTemplateMock); // passing in the mock
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Spring's mocking support for RestTemplate rather than trying to mock RestTemplate - much nicer:

Create a mock rest service server binding it to your RestTemplate:

```
MockRestServiceServer mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
```

Record a call to that mock server e.g.

```
  mockServer.expect(requestTo("some url").andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
                .andRespond(withSuccess("addSuccessResult", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));
```

Then verify the mocks have been called:

```
mockServer.verify();
```

See https://objectpartners.com/2013/01/09/rest-client-testing-with-mockrestserviceserver/