# Trying to mock RestTemplate with MockRestServiceServer but body is always null

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, null, resttemplate

I am trying to mock `RestTemplate` with `MockRestServiceServer`. When I am debugging my test, the response entity has the good status and content-type (tested with multiple status and content-type to check the differences), but the body is **always** `null`.

```
    final String uri = "/uri";
    final String notNullJsonString = "{}";
    // restTemplate is autowired
    final MockRestServiceServer mockRestServiceServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
    mockRestServiceServer.expect(
        MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo(new URI(uri))
    ).andRespond(
        MockRestResponseCreators.withStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(notNullJsonString)
    );
```

Best regards,

Comment: Can you please look into this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37781982/mocking-a-rest-call-with-mockrestserviceserver

Comment: I have already seen this post. I am not using another restTemplate, I use the injected restTemplate.

Comment: It might happen if you use interceptor and given interceptor does not getting executed request

Answer (score 16):

I had the exact same problem:

Try adding .bufferContent() to the MockRestServiceServer

```
final MockRestServiceServer mockRestServiceServer = MockRestServiceServer
      .bindTo(requestTemplate)
      .bufferContent()
      .build()
```